# Why the var i in the promise then function is undefined?

Tags: promise, closures

When I play with promise, I find this code works very strange, the var " i " in then function is undefined.

```
function api(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                resolve(['x','y','z']);
            },2000)
        });
}


for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    (function (){//closure
        var i=i;
        api().then(function(re){
            console.log(re[i]);
        })
    })()
}

// this broken too
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    (function(){
        var i=i;
        console.log(i);
    })()
}
```

I think it is because defined a var as the same name, but in other situation, this type of define is all ok. I ofen change the var itself this way.
Below all work fine

```
function api(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                resolve(['x','y','z']);
            },2000)
        });
}


for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    (function (){//closure
        var j=i;
        api().then(function(re){
            console.log(re[j]);
        })
    })()
}

for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    var i=i;
    console.log(i);
}

for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    var i=i;
    (function(){
        console.log(i);
    })()
}

var a=1;
var a=a.toString();
```

Comment: `var i=i` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Kevin B It's a closure variable, I need it to keep the value.

Comment: right, but, that's not even close to how you do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you define `i` within the closure, it will clobber the `i` from outside the scope (which will then be inaccessible). In Javascript, vars are scoped to the function, not to the block, so declaring `var i = i` within the for loop is purely redundant.

> ### var hoisting
>
> Because variable declarations (and declarations in general) are
>   processed before any code is executed, declaring a variable anywhere
>   in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top. This also means
>   that a variable can appear to be used before it's declared. This
>   behavior is called "hoisting", as it appears that the variable
>   declaration is moved to the top of the function or global code.

See more on [MDN's `var` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

---

For more information about why hoisting hides the root cause, compare what happens when you change `var i = i` to `let i = i`, given that `let` is not hoisted the way that `var` is:

```js
function api(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                resolve(['x','y','z']);
            },2000)
        });
}


for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    (function (){//closure
        let i=i;
        api().then(function(re){
            console.log(re[i]);
        })
    })()
}
```

Here, `let i = i` reveals `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined`, which reveals the root cause that the name collision makes the `i` in the outer scope inaccessible. Contrast this with `var i`, *which compiles without error due to the hoisting*, and [with a similar script in `bash`](http://pastebin.com/p62kDJHq) (which treats scope differently than Javascript and consequently works the way you describe).

Comment: Thanks! I never heard var hoisting before, so totaly don't know why. But declaring a var in closure in my situation is needed, otherwise the code do not work properly.

Comment: @gonnavis Glad to help! Don't get me wrong, having a separate variable declared in the closure makes good sense. There's just no way to say `var /* inner */ i = /* outer */ i` without putting some other intermediate name in there.

Comment: Uhhh, this isn't actual a hoisting issue at all.  The closure makes it's own new scope because it's a new function so this answer's explanation is entirely wrong.  So, the issue is that they are defining a new `var i` which hides the parent `var i`.  They could change the name of the second `var i` to something new or they could pass it into the closure (which is the usual choice) in order to solve this problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 The closure marks a new scope, but it would have visibility into the outer scope's `i` if there weren't a conflicting name; furthermore, in a language without hoisting, you could argue that the name clobbering only happens _after_ you get the outer scope's value of `i`, but that doesn't work in Javascript because the position of `var` doesn't matter as the hoisting quote explains. So, though hoisting is only _a part of_ the full reason, I do think it's an important and unintuitive part.

Comment: No, hoisting has absolutely nothing to do with this issue.  In fact, the second `var i` is declared at the top level of it's containing function so hoisting doesn't change a single thing with that declaration.  The issue is purely one of naming conflict between an inner scope and a higher scope.

Comment: @jfriend00 Please see [this example in bash](http://pastebin.com/p62kDJHq) about how `var i = i` would have useful meaning in a non-hoisting language (bash). Whether or not you can call bash a real programming language, I hope you get a sense about why I disagree with "hoisting doesn't change a single thing".

Comment: The issue is purely one of a local variable declaration overriding/hiding a higher scoped variable of the same name.  I won't argue any more about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122937/discussion-between-jeff-bowman-and-jfriend00).